# Difference in path xxxx/./xxxx and xxxx/xxxx

Tags: path

is there a difference in the following two paths?

```
Path="/apps/WebLogicPPT/user_projects/wlsPPTDomain/./applications/ssc/sscoc_web_sos_11.1ps_v0.1.ear"

Path="/apps/WebLogicPPT/user_projects/wlsPPTDomain/applications/ssc/sscoc_web_sos_11.1ps_v0.1.ear"
```

Comment: There should not be any, but since you ask I assume that you have experienced some kind of problem with it. Could you share that with us?

Comment: Hi Anders, i am not experiencing problems with this, luckily. Is there really no difference on this?

Comment: Until proven differently, I assume it isn't. Usual filesystem behaviour is that `.` represents *current directory* and `..` represents *parent directory*.

Comment: Anders, i find your answer logical, can you please put that as your answer so that i can do a proper closure (for the benefit of the ones who are searching for related answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most operating systems, `.` represents *the current directory* and `..` represents *the parent directory*.

Given a file structure like this:

```
C:.
└───foo
    └───bar
```

You can list the contents of `bar` in numerous ways:

```
dir c:\foo\bar
dir c:\foo\.\.\.\.\.\bar
dir c:\foo\..\foo\..\foo\bar\.
...
```